# NET 5.0 WebJob only wants to write to my local Blob storage

Tags: .net-core, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobssdk, azure-webjobs-continuous

We're halfway through 2021 and all the WebJob answers I'm finding are pretty old.. maybe there's a new wrinkle I'm missing

This picture from my Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer says it all:

[image]

On my machnine, I use this `appsettings.Development.json` file -- allowing my dotnet console to talk with my Azurite storage instance (Azurite is running from my local Docker)

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",

    "ContosoData": "Initial Catalog=Contoso;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False;Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;"
  }
}
```

In production, these lines from `Program.cs` will override the above with my 'real' connection strings...

```cs
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, conf) =>
{

    var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

    _configuration = conf
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
})
```

... which I've saved into my Web App Service's Configuration page:
[image]

The singular method in my Functions.cs is successfully detected and called - I'm using this output attribute to write to the Blob storage

```cs
public class Functions
{
    [Singleton]
    public async static Task CopyDates(
        [TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo myTimer, 
        [Blob("tsl-updater-logs/log.txt", FileAccess.Write)] TextWriter logger)
    {

        logger.WriteLine($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
}
```

Because the function is marked with `RunOnStartup = true` my dashboard soon shows the job to be `Started` or `Running` after I publish the job - but I never see the log.txt file get written into my Blob storage container

What am I missing?

Oh.. if you must know.. these are my nugets:

[image]

## UPDATE:

> Adding: Full source of my Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

 class Program
    {
        public static IConfiguration _configuration;
        public static IServiceCollection _services;

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new HostBuilder();

            builder
                //.UseEnvironment("Development")
                .ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
                {
                    b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
                    b.AddAzureStorageBlobs();
                    b.AddTimers();
                    //b.AddDashboardLogging();

                })
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, conf) =>
                {

                    var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

                    _configuration = conf
                        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                        .Build();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
                {
                    b.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
                    b.AddConsole();
                })
                .ConfigureServices(svc =>
                {
                    svc.AddDbContext<Models.DataWareHouseCtx>(opt =>
                        opt.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DataWareHouse"))
                            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true)
                            .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking));

                    svc.AddDbContext<Models.TslDataContext>(opt =>
                        opt.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("ThingStatusLocation"))
                            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true)
                            .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll));

                    _services = svc;

                });
                //.UseConsoleLifetime();


            var host = builder.Build();

            
            using (host)
            {
                await host.RunAsync();
            }
        }

 
    }
```

## UPDATE 2:

> Output of log dashboard

```
[07/13/2021 20:53:10 > ef3fc6: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopped
[07/13/2021 21:24:12 > ef3fc6: SYS INFO] Detected WebJob file/s were updated, refreshing WebJob
[07/13/2021 21:24:12 > ef3fc6: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
[07/13/2021 21:24:12 > ef3fc6: SYS INFO] WebJob singleton setting is False
[07/13/2021 21:24:13 > ef3fc6: SYS INFO] Run script 'run.cmd' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[07/13/2021 21:24:13 > ef3fc6: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[07/13/2021 21:24:13 > ef3fc6: INFO] 
[07/13/2021 21:24:13 > ef3fc6: INFO] D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\My.WebJob.Updater\s02hk5ti.50s>dotnet My.WebJob.Updater.dll  
[07/13/2021 21:24:14 > ef3fc6: INFO] info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Blobs.Config.BlobsExtensionConfigProvider[0]
[07/13/2021 21:24:14 > ef3fc6: INFO]       registered http endpoint = 
[07/13/2021 21:24:14 > ef3fc6: INFO] info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
[07/13/2021 21:24:14 > ef3fc6: INFO]       LoggerFilterOptions
[07/13/2021 21:24:14 > ef3fc6: INFO]       {
[07/13/2021 21:24:14 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "MinLevel": "Information",
[07/13/2021 21:24:14 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "Rules": []
[07/13/2021 21:24:14 > ef3fc6: INFO]       }
[07/13/2021 21:24:14 > ef3fc6: INFO] info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
[07/13/2021 21:24:14 > ef3fc6: INFO]       FunctionResultAggregatorOptions
[07/13/2021 21:24:14 > ef3fc6: INFO]       {
[07/13/2021 21:24:14 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "BatchSize": 1000,
[07/13/2021 21:24:14 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "FlushTimeout": "00:00:30",
[07/13/2021 21:24:14 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "IsEnabled": true
[07/13/2021 21:24:14 > ef3fc6: INFO]       }
[07/13/2021 21:24:14 > ef3fc6: INFO] info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
[07/13/2021 21:24:14 > ef3fc6: INFO]       QueuesOptions
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]       {
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "BatchSize": 16,
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "NewBatchThreshold": 16,
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "MaxPollingInterval": "00:01:00",
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "MaxDequeueCount": 5,
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "VisibilityTimeout": "00:00:00",
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "MessageEncoding": "Base64"
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]       }
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO] info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]       SingletonOptions
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]       {
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "LockPeriod": "00:00:15",
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "ListenerLockPeriod": "00:01:00",
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "LockAcquisitionTimeout": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "LockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:05",
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "ListenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00"
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]       }
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO] info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]       BlobsOptions
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]       {
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "MaxDegreeOfParallelism": 16
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]       }
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO] info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.JobHostService[0]
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]       Starting JobHost
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO] info: Host.Startup[0]
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]       Found the following functions:
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]       Ross.WebJob.Tsl.Updater.Functions.CopyDates
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]       
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO] info: Host.Startup[0]
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO]       Job host started
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO] Hosting environment: Production
[07/13/2021 21:24:15 > ef3fc6: INFO] Content root path: D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\My.WebJob.Updater\s02hk5ti.50s\
[07/13/2021 21:34:22 > ef3fc6: SYS INFO] Detected WebJob file/s were updated, refreshing WebJob
[07/13/2021 21:34:22 > ef3fc6: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopping
[07/13/2021 21:34:27 > ef3fc6: ERR ] Thread was being aborted.
[07/13/2021 21:34:27 > ef3fc6: SYS INFO] WebJob process was aborted
[07/13/2021 21:34:27 > ef3fc6: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopped
[07/13/2021 21:34:28 > ef3fc6: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
[07/13/2021 21:34:28 > ef3fc6: SYS INFO] Run script 'run.cmd' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[07/13/2021 21:34:28 > ef3fc6: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[07/13/2021 21:34:28 > ef3fc6: INFO] 
[07/13/2021 21:34:28 > ef3fc6: INFO] D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\My.WebJob.Tsl.Updater\s02hk5ti.50s>dotnet Ross.WebJob.Tsl.Updater.dll  
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO] info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Blobs.Config.BlobsExtensionConfigProvider[0]
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]       registered http endpoint = 
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO] info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]       LoggerFilterOptions
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]       {
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "MinLevel": "Information",
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "Rules": []
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]       }
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO] info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]       FunctionResultAggregatorOptions
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]       {
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "BatchSize": 1000,
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "FlushTimeout": "00:00:30",
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "IsEnabled": true
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]       }
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO] info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]       QueuesOptions
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]       {
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "BatchSize": 16,
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "NewBatchThreshold": 16,
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "MaxPollingInterval": "00:01:00",
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "MaxDequeueCount": 5,
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "VisibilityTimeout": "00:00:00",
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "MessageEncoding": "Base64"
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]       }
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO] info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]       SingletonOptions
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]       {
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "LockPeriod": "00:00:15",
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "ListenerLockPeriod": "00:01:00",
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "LockAcquisitionTimeout": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "LockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:05",
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "ListenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00"
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]       }
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO] info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]       BlobsOptions
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]       {
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]         "MaxDegreeOfParallelism": 16
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]       }
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO] info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.JobHostService[0]
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]       Starting JobHost
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO] info: Host.Startup[0]
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]       Found the following functions:
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]       My.WebJob.Updater.Functions.CopyDates
[07/13/2021 21:34:29 > ef3fc6: INFO]       
[07/13/2021 21:34:30 > ef3fc6: INFO] info: Host.Startup[0]
[07/13/2021 21:34:30 > ef3fc6: INFO]       Job host started
[07/13/2021 21:34:30 > ef3fc6: INFO] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[07/13/2021 21:34:30 > ef3fc6: INFO] Hosting environment: Production
[07/13/2021 21:34:30 > ef3fc6: INFO] Content root path: D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\My.WebJob.Updater\s02hk5ti.50s\
[07/13/2021 22:34:28 > ef3fc6: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[07/14/2021 10:34:28 > ef3fc6: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
```

## Update 3: Finally onto something - TLS Version Not Supported

> Snippet from Output pane in VS when I choose to View Streaming Logs

```
Application:Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
Application:   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
Application:   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
Application:   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Application:   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
Application:   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.DownloadBlockList(BlockListingFilter blockListingFilter, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)
Application:   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics.AzureBlobTraceListener.AppendStreamToBlob(Stream stream)
Application:   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics.AzureBlobTraceListener.ConsumeBuffer()
Application:Request Information
Application:RequestID:6bbeae68-701e-009c-0ad8-787fc9000000
Application:RequestDate:Wed, 14 Jul 2021 17:46:01 GMT
Application:StatusMessage:The TLS version of the connection is not permitted on this storage account.
Application:ErrorCode:TlsVersionNotPermitted
```

Comment: Is `AzureWebJobsStorage` set to something valid in production?

Comment: @DavidG - I believe so because other webjob infrastructure-ish containers are in there, like  `azure-jobs-host-archive`, `azure-jobs-host-output`, `azure-webjobs-dashboard` and `azure-webjobs-host`

So, I believe some of those are used to support singleton locks, etc.. and others maybe drive the dashboard logging I presume. Some of this may be residual leftovers, as my prior attempts last week were WebJob 1.x style code

Comment: @DavidG - I created a console app [based off this quickstart guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet) and used my connection string there, successfully connecting to my `tsllogging` storage. The quick start app I created then was able to create a new container and upload a Blob into it.

Answer (score 0):

There may've been multiple problems I was fighting, but, I finally conquered.
Here's the things I did to resolve my woes:

1.) I needed to put `AzureWebJobsStorage` key-value into my `Application Settings` (perhaps former iterations of webjobs would get it from `Connection Strings` - but no longer)

2.) I was using some `5.0.0 beta` NuGet packages that were probably failing on #1, so when I rolled them wayyyy back. (Especially Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage - which I rolled back to 3.x.x - which is when I started getting the TLS version errors shown in my logs. The 4.0.4 is stable and happy)

Here's my current state of NuGet:
[image]